# How to decrypt a message that each of the encrypted elements are 2 letters?

Tags: encryption

The decryptor can't read the encrypted message except for underscore

I've tried searching and using the methods of arrays and strings but none of them worked

```js
let secret = "1a_1b_1a";
let secretUp = secret.toUpperCase();

let messageArray = [];
let message = "";

let i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < secretUp.length; i = i + 2){
  let j = i + 2;
  if (secretUp[i, j] === "1A"){
    messageArray.push("A")
  } else if (secretUp[i, j] === "1B") {
    messageArray.push("B")
  } else if (secretUp[i] === "_") {
    messageArray.push(" ");
    i--;
    continue;
  } else {
    messageArray.push(secretUp[i, j])
  };

  message = messageArray.join("");

};

console.log(message)
```

I expected it to be "A B A"
But instead, i got "_ _"

Comment: Hint: use `console.log(secretUp[i, j])` in the loop to check it is looking at what you want it to look at.

Comment: it returns
_
_
undefined

Comment: You're probably better off using the [substring() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Answer (score 0):

After a while of thinking and some researching, I did this and made the code work

```js
let secret = "1a_1b_1a";
let secretUp = secret.toUpperCase();

let messageArray = [];
let message = "";

let i = 0;
while(i < secretUp.length){
  if(secretUp.substring(i, i + 1) === "_"){
    messageArray.push(" ");
    i++;
  } else {
    let j = i + 2;
    if (secretUp.substring(i, j) === "1A"){
      messageArray.push("A")
    } else if (secretUp.substring(i, j) === "1B") {
      messageArray.push("B")
    } else {
      messageArray.push(secretUp.substring(i, j))
    };
    i = i + 2;
  };
```